# Is there an overview/list of CTAN mirrors which support zsync?

Tags: ctan

Starting from http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html I tried to gather information about support or at least (eventually dropped, but at least discussed) plans for it, but also $SEARCH_ENGINE doesn't give any usable results (finds some `.zsync` files and one can guess from the hostname and URL path that it is related to tex, but an official statement would be nicer than trial and error :)

Answer (score 3):

The official list of CTAN mirrors is made public under the URL http://www.ctan.org/mirrors/. As you can see there, only http, ftp, and rsync are currently supported. I am not aware of any need at the moment to extend this list -- and no plans at any stage into this direction.
Possibly some of the mirrors might support zsync. But this is not recorded in the central mirror database from which the URL above is fed.